# I'm looking for an "angry" font

Tags: font-recommendation

**Background:**

- It's for joke cards / t-shirt where the font does not match the
  statement.
- I'm a UX guy interested in graphic design and typography
  but NOT a designer.

**Attempts:**

My first thought was to use Blackletter. It's visually oppressive plus was a fave of Hitler and the Nazis. The only problem is that most blackletter fonts are illegible, especially on fabric. One of the cleanest / most legible I've found is Black Baron.

Lombardic fonts are too ... flowery.

I've tried grunge fonts - such as Astonished - but that doesn't evoke "anger" to me. Nihilism - maybe.  Anarchy - maybe. But not anger.

I've also (mostly) rejected spray paint fonts.

So, rather than reinvent the wheel - what fonts would the community recommend?

- I'm looking for a font that's forceful, authoritative (preferably
  evoking "I'm angry")
- The font needs to be legible for a phrase as opposed to a single word.

For instance "Metallica" is easy to read. The phrases that will be used are along the line of:

"If you want to "x" you need to "y" and are accompanied by graphics.

Comment: Try fonts from "rotunda" type. I would say that it's hard to make an angry (so rather vibrating, anxious attacking feeling) font that is easy to read. After all it's hard to read angry people. That's why so many metal bans have so spiky, hard to read typeface logos. TO invoke that angry attack feeling.

Comment: How many of these do you need to do? I would go for hand lettering it. Sure you can find fonts that seem angry, but fonts usually convey some sort of formality which I think will work against your message.

Comment: ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎⠀ ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎

Comment: Typefaces *never* convey emotion. It's the rest of the design which will do that. Helvetica can appears just as "angry" as Times... it's all context.

Comment: Trace back to the work of Jamie Reid for the Sex Pistols... they were pretty angry, at least John Lydon was / still is. Reid added to the discord by using collage and tearing bold letters out of news print - might be a bit too much work for you but a good reference for deliberately creating a bit of anger and chaos. https://bit.ly/2qAGAco

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess there's no established way to present angriness with typography. One can in theory create such practice if he controls some very popular information channel, but I haven't seen it's already happened. Thus there's no way to select an angry font for the following text:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...

If there's some angriness, it must be in the text content and auxiliary graphics.

We can show what angry mood causes to manual writings. If one is angry his manual writing very likely has regressed to a more primitive level. It's not as readable as the same text written by a calm person and some not so well premeditated expletives can be included. So, a fast done and somehow accented handwriting can create an illusion of angry writer and somehow fitting text & auxiliary graphic content can make the illusion stronger.

I guess it's not possible to get the same as computer font. The needed irregularity doesn't exist. A genius programmer maybe could generate a detoriating algorithm to create the angriness reflecting regression to a whole text block, but this is not achieved by having regular glyphs.

If there's something important written, the text should be as readable as possible - that's the first requirement, so the writing cannot be much more accented than quite normal manual lettering. The mood should be set with the text content and graphics. An example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Finding a font that evokes *`I'm angry`* may be somewhat subjective. In graphic design when it comes to representing concepts, the base term or terms must be analyzed in depth. The most immediate method is to find synonyms and try to find the ones that best fit a graphic representation:

[image: synonyms]

What can be the relationship between a typeface and a furious, exasperated, irritated state?

I particularly remember the handwritten notes my mother left on my desk when she wanted to scolder me for some reason and I wasn't at home. I don't think it's casual all the fonts you have stated as possible are handwritten or evoke or simulate being done manually.

[image: angry note]

*This is just an example googling [angry note](https://www.google.com/search?q=angry%20note&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&sxsrf=ACYBGNQQ9iKR_bV3RMZThdCbJf0K6ejNhQ:1574190764755&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmhNfK_fblAhVFzIUKHdwuDOcQ_AUIEigB&biw=1602&bih=1208#imgrc=_)*

---

I would look for these characteristics by following those concepts:

- Manuscript
- Bold
- Condensed and/or italic (fast strokes)
- Sharp
- Rough

Try looking for them in [myfonts](https://www.myfonts.com/search/text%3Amanuscript+text%3Abold+text%3Acondensed+text%3Asharp+text%3Arough+text%3Amarker/fonts/) advanced search.

---

**Sample fonts**

### [image: suzee]

Gneisenauette Regular Font

[image: Gneisenauette]

---

Riptide Font

[image: Riptide]

Cult Let Plain Font

[image: Cult]

---

Banshee Font

[image: Banshee]

---

Bendigo Plain Font

[image: Bendigo]

---

Flight Plain Font

[image: Flight]

---

Answer (score 1):

You'll more than likely find something that fits the bill on [Blambot](https://blambot.com/). There's a small enough selection to look through them pretty quickly. I might recommend Ripsnort, Big Bloke, Trash Cinema, You Murderer, Chainsawz, Entrails, and Always Angry.

(After checking, it's possible their license requirements have changed since I last visited. Make sure your use is in compliance with their licenses.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this looks pretty angry, via http://www.ransomizer.com/:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anger is an easy emotion for a font to express, and (like you said with blackletter) any font you do use is likely to be typographically limited, or hard to read. I think it's easier to express using what you do *with* the font. Basically, imagine the font is being placed onto the paper by someone getting angrier and angrier as they go along, so imagine they're doing it with an ink stamp or a typewriter and by the end of the message they're really smashing the letters down onto the paper, smearing the ink all over the paper and almost about to bash a hole through it.

So what I would do is choose a font with several weights going up from light to extra bold (maybe Franklin Gothic, or Helvetica, or Roboto, or a monospace font with a lot of weights to suggest a typewriter), start normal in a light weight and as the statement gets angrier start to go up into bolder weights and distort the font more, overprinting the same letter multiple times from slightly different angles, twisting the characters, like the person is getting angrier and angrier and smashing harder and harder onto the paper. One font you could use, though, is [Shatter](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/shatter/), and it's based on Helvetica Bold, so going into that from Helvetica at the climax could make the anger really intuitive. Or you could assemble something like it in the font of your choice.